# Reactjs - import issues with Bootstrap 4 Popovers component

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, popover

I have tried everything in my skillset to import popovers in ReactJS, but I didn't manage.

I need popover to be triggered when user clicks on 'FA' icon.

```
 <FontAwesome
   className='offButton'
   name='question'
   size='lg'
   style={{ textShadow: '0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)' }}
 />
```

I have tried to follow steps from this bootstrap 4 official guide, but didn't work.

I've read that some parts of it got deprecated in later versions, and I'm not also sure if I have to change something in my webpack configuration.

If someone was importing it recently and remembers all of the steps - would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you just using regular Bootstrap JS library? Try https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers instead

Comment: react-bootstrap doesn't support Bootstrap 4: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1187.  You could look at reactstrap, which does support v4 - I found it personally too early in the development cycle though.